# Store values in database table using php explode function

Tags: php, sql, insert, implode

I have a form with 4 or more checkboxes.The form is created by a while loop and has data from database table.Each checkbox represents a gift and each gift has a unique id (id1=1, id2=2, id3=3, ...) in database.So user can choose one or more gifts and click the submit button to store his choice.So I need php `implode()` function to get the string of what choices user made.For example if he chooses the 1st and the 2nd checkbox/gift the value that must be stored should be `1, 2`.Instead of this I always have different stored data and don't match with user choices..Any ideas?

Form :

```
  <form method='post' action='insert.php'>
      .
      .
      .

     while($row_select4 = $stmt_select4->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){

        if($form_points>=$row_select4['points']) {

             $points = $row_select4['points'];  


           echo '

              <div>
                 <div class="feed-activity-list"><div style="border: 0.5px solid green; border-right-style:none;" class="input-group m-b"><span class="input-group-addon"> 
                 <input type="checkbox" onclick="enable_form();" id="checkbox" name="opt[]" value="'.$points.'"></span>
                 <input type="hidden" name="opt2[]" value="'.$row_select4['id'].'">


                 <div class="feed-element">
                 <a href="profile.html" class="pull-left">
                 <img alt="image" class="img-circle" src="'. $row_select4['image_url']. '">
                 </a>';

  ?>

   <button type="submit" id="submit" name="eksasrgirwsh" class="btn btn-w-m btn-primary">ΕΞΑΡΓΥΡΩΣΗ</button> 
                 </form>
```

Also (before insertion into table) :

```
if(isset($_POST['opt2'])){



            foreach ($_POST['opt2'] as $value) {
                $gift = $_POST['opt2'];   

                $sliced = array_slice($gift, 0, -1);
                $gift_id = implode(", ", $sliced);
                }
```

This is what I use to get the chosen gift_ids and create the string of them

Form updated:

```
<input type="hidden" disabled="disabled" name="opt2[]" value="'.$row_select4['id'].'">
```

Code for getting gift_ids:

```
foreach ($_POST['opt2'] as $value) {
                $gift = $_POST['opt2'];   

                $gift_id = implode(", ", $gift);
               }
```

Comment: why are you use foreach for implode?

Comment: Sorry I didn't notice your question.I need implode to get the gift ids as string and store the string into a table

Answer (score 0):

No need for `array_slice`
in your php code:

```
$gift = $_POST['opt2'];
$gift_id = implode(", ", $gift);
```

By using this, you can get the result you wish.

**Edit:**

The reason you get all 1,2,3,4 is that you use `hidden` for gift id.

Try to add `disabled="disabled"` to the hidden tag which you dont want send to server. After this, you can get correct ids using `$_POST['opt2']`

Comment: Each checkbox represents a gift and each gift has a unique id.The result I get using this code is `1, 2, 3, 4` although i choose 2 of 4 checkboxes (1st and 2nd).So I use slice to remove the last checkbox..

Comment: Sorry! what is your `opt[]` use for?

Comment: There two different values.Points and Gift_id.For example I get sum of points if user chooses 2 checkboxes and their gift_id as string..

Comment: Now I store `NULL` on the table..I included `disabled="disabled"` as you coded and I use this before insertion `if(isset($_POST['opt2'])){
            
           
            
                foreach ($_POST['opt2'] as $value) {
                    $gift = $_POST['opt2'];   
                    
                    $sliced = array_slice($gift, 0, -1);
                    $gift_id = explode(", ", $gift);
                    }
                echo $gift_id;`. Is this right?

Comment: I was wrong!For example I choose the 1st checkbox which has id=1 on the database and I stored `1, 2` instead of  `1`.

Comment: Man I cannot figure this out!If you could help me more I would be grateful

Comment: if you use `disabled` it mean it wont send to server, you can add if checkbox been click, remove `disabled` attribute